# How to obtain the preinstalled image?

Tags: 16.04, dell, preinstallation

I have a Latitude 5480 which came pre-installed with Windows 10. I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 myself but failed to make some of the drivers work correctly. I would like to try the dedicated, pre-installed Ubuntu image that comes with this laptop. The problem is I cant find this image anywhere. [Ubuntu hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Dell/?query=5480%20&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Server&release=&level=Any) only states that the hardware is supported, but doesn't provide any download link.

I would appreciate all help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu itself does not provide any specific version of the operating system dedicated to a specific laptop's "brand".

The ones which come with a laptop are mostly same ISO that Ubuntu provides or a tweaked one by the laptop manufacture.

You can have access to all available ISOs from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: So how can I Access those "tweaked" ones?

Comment: Not from the Ubuntu, you should ask for them (if any) from your laptop manufacture.